# data-index not working, How to delete child records in lookup relation custom object?

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, salesforce-id

in another project is working with the same structure, but not with this one. I can't see the error. thanks for helpme

***I can't delete the product, I want to get the ID by "data index" and delete the customer associated product on my form. my custom object Produto__c is a lookap for Cliente__c***

look my code:

**inlineEditCtrl.apxc**

```
    @AuraEnabled
public static Boolean deleteProduto(Id ProId) {
    system.debug('in delete');
    Produto__c p = [SELECT Id FROM Produto__c WHERE Cliente__c =: ProId];

    try{
        delete p;
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e){
        return false;
    }

}
```

**//method to bring a customer's product list by its ID.**

```
    @AuraEnabled
public static list<Produto__c> getProdutolist(Id showId){

    return [SELECT Id, Name, Modelo__c, Estado__c FROM Produto__c WHERE Cliente__c = :showId LIMIT 3];

}
```

**inlineEditRow.cmp**

```
<aura:attribute name="Pro" type="Produto__c" />
<aura:attribute name="ProdutoList" type="List"/>

<aura:iteration items="{!v.ProdutoList}" var="Pro" >                                            
                                        <tr>

                                            <th scope="row">
                                                <div class="slds-truncate" >
                                                    <ui:outputText value="{!Pro.Name}" />
                                                </div>
                                            </th>
                                            <th scope="row">
                                                <div class="slds-truncate" >
                                                    <ui:outputText value="{!Pro.Modelo__c}"/>
                                                </div>
                                            </th>
                                            <th scope="row">
                                                <div class="slds-truncate">
                                                    <ui:outputText value="{!Pro.Estado__c}" />
                                                </div>
                                            </th>
                                            <!-- criado o data-index para pegar o id do Produto.-->
                                            <button data-index="{!Pro.Id}" class="slds-button slds-button_destructive" onclick="{!c.deleteProduto}" value="{!Pro.Name}">Deletar</button> 
                                        </tr>                                            
                                    </aura:iteration>
```

**inlineEditRow.js**

```
    deleteProduto : function(component, event, helper) {        
    var nomeProduto = event.currentTarget.value;
    var id = event.currentTarget.dataset.index; 
    if(confirm('Deseja Deletar o Produto : ' + nomeProduto + ' ?!'))
        helper.deleteProduto(component, event, id);

},
```

**inlineEditRowHelper.js**

```
deleteProduto: function(component, event, id){        
    var currentRecordId = id;          
    var deletarproduto = component.get('c.deleteProduto');        
    // pass the all selected record's Id's to apex method 
    deletarproduto.setParams({
        "ProId" : currentRecordId

    });         
    deletarproduto.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        //store state of response
        var state = response.getState();            
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {                
            console.log(state);
            if (response.getReturnValue() != '') {
                // if getting any error while delete the records , then display a alert msg/
                alert('The following error has occurred. while Delete record-->' + response.getReturnValue());
            } else {
                console.log('check it--> delete successful');
            }
            // call the onLoad function for refresh the List view 
            location.reload();
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(deletarproduto);
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: We need more than "not working" in order to help you. What problem are you experiencing? What debugging have you done? I don't see anything specifically wrong with your code, so short of debugging logs, etc, we probably can't help you.

Comment: Sorry, I can't delete the product, I want to get the ID by "data index" and delete the customer associated product on my form. my custom object PRODUCT is a lookap for CUSTOMER.

Comment: I added a picture in post

Comment: @Joanes I think we understand what you're *trying* to do. We don't understand *what's wrong*. Please [edit] to provide specific, detailed description of the behavior, including any information you can glean from the browser's console logs or your Apex logs.

Comment: I added the log screens

Comment: no error appears, simply does not delete the product

Answer (score 0):

You've not provided the full context of what you're doing, but my best "educated guess" is you need to provide more context for the delete operation. You're probably attempting to delete the actual product instead of the product from an order or opportunity line item. Your query in your @AuraEnabled method also needs to have that context as well so it knows what to delete it from. Your comments mention a lookup relationship. These relationships need to be passed to your method to provide the proper context so the query will return to correct record.

Comment: I added a picture in post

Comment: Yes, I am trying to delete a Produto__c, corresponding to the Cliente__c.  Produto _c is lookup of Cliente _c. OBS: I edited the post.  but it is not working. No error appears. how would i have to put in @AuraEnabled?